# Использование await внутри Task C#

Tags: c#

Я не могу понять, есть ли смысл использовать оператор `await` внутри `Task`

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    // Тут еще ещё пару разных методов

    using (WebClient req = new WebClient())
    {
        ipAddress = await req.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://api.ipify.org");
    }

    // И тут тоже еще пару разных методов
});
```

Comment: Именно здесь нет смысла использовать `Task.Run`. И используйте `HttpClient`. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вопрос сводится к вопросу "нужно ли использовать await вообще?". Асинхронная функция может быть запущена напрямую в вашем коде или через Task или каким либо другим удобным вам способом - оператору `await` не важно, как именно запустили функцию, в которой он находится.

Другой вопрос - надо или вам использовать Task при запуске асинхронной функции, но это уже сильно от вашей задачи зависит.